# Mouse clicks do not work correctly in QT applications

Tags: mouse, qt

I run Gnome as my desktop environment, and the mouse works fine. However, when I try to use a QT application, mouse clicks don't work correctly. For example, if I click and release inside a text editor, it begins highlighting the text as if I'm still holding down the mouse button. It's as if it doesn't register the *mouse up* event.

Any ideas why this might be happening, or how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: I'm seeing this problem as well and haven't found any useful information or work arounds.

Comment: This may be a cause, although upstream has closed the bug under the hope that Qt 5.12+ will fix this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54085

Answer (score 3):

I find that simply tapping my touch screen after this happens clears the issue. This is with Ubuntu 18.04 with an Acer Spin 1 . This usually happens when I'm using FreeCAD.

Comment: Same problem here, and tapping the touchscreen solved it. Go figure... I was having problems with Arduino IDE, Audacity and Robo3t. Thanks, that bug was really annoying.

Answer (score 2):

**Finally, a general solution!**

The problem is caused by Qt's support for touch screens. What I've done is use `xinput` to disable the touch screen:

```
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06E5:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
[... bunch of keyboard stuff]
```

The "ELAN Touchscreen" input is the one we care about. It's id is 13. So:

```
$ xinput --disable 13
```

With the touch screen input turned off, the problem no longer happens. I don't have to restart the Qt applications that are already running. Touch can be reenabled with:

```
$ xinput --enable 13
```

[This AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446421/disabling-touch-screen-only-temporarily) shows other ways to turn off touch. Unfortunately, I do not know of a way to turn off touch only for a specific application, or only for Qt applications.

The reason the problem did not happen with Xephyr (as described below) is because Xephyr starts without support for touch events.

---

(I'm keeping this information around as it may help people diagnose similar issues in the future, or people looking for a finer-grained solution.)

I ran into this problem while trying to run Qt 5 applications under a Gnome desktop. I found that if I run the Qt application in a Xephyr session, the issue goes away:

```
$ Xephyr :1 -screen 1240x800 &
$ DISPLAY=:1 path/to/executable
```

Xephyr is an Xserver that can act as a client of another Xserver. (I've also tried Xnest, and it works too.) By running the software in a different Xserver, it is essentially isolated from the destkop environment running on the default Xserver.

For **some** use-case scenarios, this may be a usable workaround. Unfortunately, the isolation means that cut-and-paste between the app running in Xephyr and the other apps would require adding some substantial glue.

---

I've tried `lxqt-config` to see if I could change some Qt settings to fix the problem but did not find a setting that fixed the issue.

I also tried starting the app with `-style=gtk` but that only changes the visual style without changing the behavior.

Comment: Using an Acer Spin with touhscreen I find that it works in Xephyr (I'm seeing the issue with FreeCAD), but disabling my touchscreen with xinput did not help.

Comment: Me neither @NeilenMarais with a Lenovo Yoga 700

Comment: Oh, It works now for me: first i disabled touch screen, then i kill touchegg program that acts as some kind of driver for my touchscreen. Then I restart the touchscreen and the problem disappeared. Maybe only killing touchegg is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with an ASUS Chromebook running XFCE in a chroot (Crouton).

I did manage to unset the mousedown by repeatedly poking the screen over Dolphin until (I guess?) it handled a "mouse up" event.

Answer (score 0):

this artical may help you.
https://blog.csdn.net/flfihpv259/article/details/90377827

i use cmake add below two line on my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH "lib:/usr/local/elevocsetting/lib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -g -O3 -no-pie")
```

`/usr/local/elevocsetting/lib` is my install dir

`-no-pie` can generate `application/x-application` mime type